# Lost files after mv command and denied permission

Tags: sudo, files

I have tried to move couple files with `mv` to a mounted directory, and the permission was denied. Then I have used `sudo mv`:

```
sudo mv file1.fa /mnt
```

it did not complain but now the files are nowhere to be found. I'd appreciate your help.

PS: My system is Ubuntu14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command in your question would only move one file.

Is it possible that the directory `/mnt` did not exist when you typed this command? If not, then you wouldn't get an error message, but your file would be moved to a file named `/mnt`. If you used the command again with a different filename, again you would get no error message, but the file `/mnt` would be replaced with the second file. The previously moved file would be lost in the process.

Try typing `ls -ld /mnt` to see if it is a directory, or a file that you moved to a location you didn't expect.

Comment: i agree with @Mox's answer, but have these thoughts.  If the directory /mnt existed but you'd not mounted anything into it (assuming you had write access to it), the file would be copied to that directory.  if you later 'mount device /mnt' the files in the /mnt directory are 'hidden' and the contents of device are shown.  umount to see/access hidden files.

If the `ls -ld` is hard to remember, there are alternatives, eg. `file /mnt` (what type of file is /mnt), `stat` & more ...

Comment: You are right.  The content of the second file is in /mnt but the first one is lost.. Thank you!